# How to handle UI alerts in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am completely new to MeteorJS and I just started to build my first app with it.

In my application, I want to display alerts on certain preconditions to give feedback to the user via the interface.

At the moment I am using `Session.set("alert", "This is a a warning!")` but I don't know if this is the best way to do it. Is this the common way to implement alerts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a local collection which will only exist in the browser, i.e. it won't be synchronised with the server.

Let's assume you have defined the following two templates:

```
<template name="alerts">
  {{#each alerts}}
    {{> alert}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="alert">
  <div class="alert alert-{{type}}" role="alert">{{message}}</div>
</template>
```

Next, you need to specify a local collection for alerts:

```
Alerts = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

After that, you need to create a helper function in order to set the proper context for the `alerts` template:

```
Template.alerts.helpers({
  alerts: function () {
    return Alerts.find();
  }
});
```

In addition, you can define some helper functions:

```
throwAlert = function (message, type) {
  Alerts.insert({message: message, type: type});
};

clearAlerts = function () {
  Alerts.remove({}); 
};
```

Finally, you need to include the `alerts` template into your main template with `{{> alerts}}`.

To throw alerts, you can use the `throwAlert()` function:

```
throwAlert("Oh snap! Connection lost.", "danger");
```

I have created a [MeteorPad "Leaderboard" example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/Y6vqmr54TtJRfXxYJ/Leaderboard_Alerts_Demo) which will show a client-side alert when adding points to a scientist, implemented with a local collection.